# when %NOTFOUND is NULL in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

please can you help me !
i have a PL/SQL programme

```
`DECLARE
//DECLARION OF CURSOR
BEGIN
OPEN cur_emp:
LOOP
FETCH cur_emp INTO ...;
EXIT WHEN cur_emp%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
END;
/    `
```

the question is when this loop is infinite ?
thank you

Comment: So you're saying this loop isn't terminating?

Comment: This is a standard cursor attribute question (right from the manual).  The answer from Oracle's manual states, "If FETCH never executes successfully, the EXIT WHEN condition is never TRUE and the loop is never exited."  The advocated approach is "EXIT WHEN cur_emp%NOTFOUND OR cur_emp%NOTFOUND IS NULL" which will address the NULL scenario where the fetch was never executed successfully.

Comment: @Patrick - I learn something new every day. Thank you! Please post that as an answer so it can be upvoted/accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's documentation regarding cursor attributes addresses this infinite loop risk. The answer from Oracle's manual states, "If FETCH never executes successfully, the EXIT WHEN condition is never TRUE and the loop is never exited." The advocated approach is as follows:

```
EXIT WHEN cur_emp%NOTFOUND OR cur_emp%NOTFOUND IS NULL
```

This will address the NULL scenario where the fetch was never executed successfully.